# jquery: scroll with specific DOM

Tags: javascript, scroll

Usually when I insert an element into DOM, the page will not automatically scroll. For example, at first there are divs `A` `B` `D` on page, and the browser view is on `D`.

```
A
B
D ] <= browser view
```

Then I insert `C` between `B` and `D`. The browser view now is on `C`.

```
A
B
C ] <= browser view
D
```

But I hope it on D. How could I make browser automatically scroll when inserting elements by javascript(but users can still scroll freely)?

Answer (score 0):

if you using `jquery` then trigger a [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) on the specific DOM element when your new DOM; `C` added.